# Underscore ignores optional arguments

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm thoroughly confused as to why the following underscore function is not working correctly.

```
var testArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var resultingArray = _.first(testArray, 2);
console.log(resultingArray);
```

I keep getting `1` logged to the console. I've tried a similar exercise with `_.initial`, and again it appears to ignore the optional `n` arguments. Anyone have any idea what could be going on?

Comment: Is the array being modified after it is declared? Code shown works fine

Comment: Works as expected on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2yu50dr4/), it logs `[1, 2]`, maybe you create a jsfiddle that is able to reproduce the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) and not [lodash](https://lodash.com)?

lodash behaves in the way you're describing, and its [`_.first()` method](https://lodash.com/docs#first) doesn't take any parameters other than the array itself. It specifically selects the very first element:

> `_.first(array)`
>
> Gets the first element of array.

To do this with lodash we'd instead use [its `_.take()` method](https://lodash.com/docs#take):

> `_.take(array, [n=1])`
>
> Creates a slice of array with n elements taken from the beginning.

```
var resultingArray = _.take(testArray, 2);
--> [1, 2]
```

Comment: I'm using underscore, and this is straight from their docs:

"_.first(array, [n])
Returns the first element of an array. Passing n will return the first n elements of the array."

Comment: @MattDionis running your code through my browser's JS console on underscore.js's website returns `[1, 2]`. Doing the same on lodash's website returns `1`. This is why I'm thinking you may not actually be using underscore.js.

Comment: @MattDionis bear in mind that the syntax is the same on both. Both have a base variable of `_`, and both have `_.first()` methods. As far as I'm aware underscore.js has always done what you quoted with its `_.first()` method, but lodash on the other hand is doing exactly what you're describing.

Comment: Bingo, we had loaded both underscore and lodash in `index.html`, but lodash came last so it looks like it took precedence.